# how to make a counting list in racket between two variables

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket, computer-science

I have been trying to make a function in Racket that counts as `(MakeList a b)` and then displays a list such that `(a, a+1, a+2, ..., b)`. I have been trying but find something online on how to create a list then add to it but have come up with very little helpful information. Any help on how to create this function would be awesome.

Comment: The function you’re looking for is [`range`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._range%29%29) from `racket/list`. If you have to implement it yourself, this sounds like homework.

Comment: What did you tried and what error did you get?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple & efficient way to do it in any Scheme or Lisp implementation:

```
(define (makelist a b)
  (do ((i b (- i 1))
       (lst '() (cons i lst)))
    ((< i a) lst)))
```

It starts with an empty list, adds `b`, keeps adding smaller ones in front, and returns the result once it reaches `a`.

Answer (score 1):

I understand this is more than likely a homework problem. As @AlexisKing points out, the `range` function already exists. But if you're stuck on writing this on your own, I'd like to offer some help. Racket is a very fun language and I don't want you to feel discouraged.

Looking on the bright side, it sounds like you mostly know what you need it to do

```
(a, a+1, a+2, ..., b)
```

So start with that

```
(define (make-list a b)
  (cons a ...))
```

What is `...` here tho? Well as you said in your expected output, `...` would be

```
(a+1 ... b)
```

So `(a+1 ... b)` is a list from `a+1` to `b` – or in other words: `(make-list (add1 a) b)`

well that's easy. Let's fill it in.

```
(define (make-list a b)
  (cons a (make-list (add1 a) b)))
```

But wait, this should be alarming to you. Why? Because we just continue on forever ...

```
(cons a (cons a+1 (cons a+2 (cons a+3 ... (cons a+Infinity ...)))))
```

We have to tell our program to stop at some point, right? But when should it stop?

Let's write out a little truth table to help us. The expression for our table will be `(make-list 0 4)`

```
a     b    previous        stop?
0     4    N/A             no
1     4    (0 ...)         no
2     4    (0 1 ...)       no
3     4    (0 1 2 ...)     no
4     4    (0 1 2 3 ...)   no
5     4    (0 1 2 3 4 ...) yes – (0 1 2 3 4) is the value we'd like
```

OK, so that makes it pretty clear. When `a` is *greater than* `b`, we can finish making our list. Remember, to signify the end of a list, we use the empty list, `empty`

```
(define (make-list a b)
  (if (> a b)
      empty
      (cons a (make-list (add1 a) b))))
```

Check it

```
(make-list 0 4) ;=> '(0 1 2 3 4)
(make-list 2 6) ;=> '(2 3 4 5 6)
(make-list 3 3) ;=> '(3)
(make-list 6 3) ;=> '()
```

Answer (score 1):

Racket's for/list function can also be used as follows:

```
(define (make-list a b)
  (for/list ((i (in-naturals))
             #:break (> i b)
             #:when (and (>= i a) (<= i b)) )
    i))

(make-list 5 10)
```

Output:

```
'(5 6 7 8 9 10)
```

But a and b have to be >= 0.

Answer (score 1):

Following loop can also be used to create such a list:

```
(define (ml a b)
  (let loop ((a a) (lst '()))
    (if (> a b)
        (reverse lst)
        (loop (add1 a) (cons a lst)))))


(ml 5 10)
```

Output:

```
'(5 6 7 8 9 10)
```